# Is a rolling start legal in F1?

Tags: rules, formula-1

In F1, there are jump start. Jump start means that you accelerates your car before all the lights go out. In this scenario, sometimes you get penalty for it, sometimes you don't.

But, recently I do watch F1 and saw Perez do what they called "rolling start" where the driver roll his tyres slowly even light still not go out. In this case, I think the driver will have a better acceleration.

It is legal?

Comment: A rolling start is a specific method of (re)starting a race where all cars are moving together before and at the moment the race (re)starts. The description you give is identical in meaning and effect to a jump start.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you're referring to the 2024 Saudi Arabian Grand Prix, where [Sergio Perez was found to have been creeping forward very slowly](https://www.gpfans.com/us/f1-news/1015706/sergio-perez-f1-jump-start-red-bull-saudi-arabian-grand-prix-2024-lando-norris/) before the lights had gone out.

This is not a "rolling start" - as Nij mentioned in their comment, a rolling start is a specific type of race start in which *every* car is moving forward at the start. If only *one* car is moving during a standing start, that's just a jump start. (Incidentally, rolling starts *are* legal in Formula One - they occur at the end of every safety car period.)

Formula One has two methods of identifying jump starts. The first is the white line at the front of the grid box: your wheels are not allowed to cross that white line before the lights go out. The second is a sensor inside the grid box, underneath the car, that can detect movement and automatically flag a driver as having jumped the start. Perez did not cross the white line, nor did he trigger the sensor, so he didn't break any rules. And having seen the footage of his "jump start", he was moving so slowly that I don't believe he could have gained any advantage from it.